# nodogsplash cannot detect wifi interface

Tags: openwrt

i'm stuck and i need any help that can point me into right direction ( thank in advance for any provided help ). i want to create a wifi access point through rassberry pi 3b+ and external wifi dungle everything is setup and working great except that nodogsplash can't detect wifi interface so here my configuration so you can check if there's any error in my configuration.

here is `/etc/config/wireless` content :

```
 config wifi-device 'wl0'
    option type 'broadcom'
    option disabled '0'
    option channel 'auto'

config wifi-device 'wlan0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '11'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    option legacy_rates '1'
    option country 'TN'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'wlan0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'OpenWrt'
    option encryption 'none'
    option network 'lan'
```

the content of `/etc/config/network`

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fda6:1455:0cd8::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config 'interface' 'wifi'
    option 'ifname' 'wlan0'
    option 'proto'  'dhcp'

config 'interface' 'wifi_2'
    option 'ifname' 'wl0'
    option 'proto'  'dhcp'
```

and last the configuration of nodogsplash under `/etc/config/nodogsplash`

```
option enabled 1 
option fwhook_enabled '1'
option gatewayinterface 'wifi'
option externalinterface 'br-lan'
option gatewayname 'OpenWrt Nodogsplash'
option maxclients '250'
option preauthidletimeout '30'
option authidletimeout '120'
option sessiontimeout '1200'
option checkinterval '600'

#TEST
option fasremoteip https://www.google.net/
option fas_secure_enabled '0'

#End TEST

list authenticated_users 'allow all'
list users_to_router 'allow tcp port 22'
list users_to_router 'allow tcp port 23'
list users_to_router 'allow tcp port 53'
list users_to_router 'allow udp port 53'
list users_to_router 'allow udp port 67'
list users_to_router 'allow tcp port 80'
list users_to_router 'allow tcp port 443'
```

so if i try this command `service nodogsplash reload` i get this error:

```
Interface wifi not detected.
Can not generate uci config. Will not start instance cfg015847.
```

thanks again for any help

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thanks for the views, i found out that nodogsplash cannot detect interface if it doesn't have an ip on his own so as a dhcp client it will not detect the wifi interface.